# How to catch events of a dynamicaly created control?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm new to Delphi and to Firemonkey.

Lets say I create a new button on my form dynamically (at run time) and that I want to catch its OnCLick event.

How do I tie my control to the onclick procedure?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must define a event handler for the onclick event with this signature on your form.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    procedure MyButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
```

and then assign the onclick event of the runtime created button like so

```
  RButton.OnClick:=MyButtonClick; //RButton is an instance to the button
```